# git pull, followed by checkout fails to update a file (permission denied) then deletes the file

Tags: git, msysgit

So here's what I've been getting every now and again recently, using msysgit on Windows 7:

```
> git pull origin master
> Enter passphrase for key '/c/Users/Dell/.ssh/id_rsa':
remote: Counting objects: 1827, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (373/373), done.
remote: Total 1019 (delta 730), reused 895 (delta 611)
Receiving objects: 100% (1019/1019), 525.92 KiB | 113 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (730/730), completed with 473 local objects.
From github.com:xxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxxx
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
error: git checkout-index: unable to create file
   path/to/my/file.cs (Permission denied)
```

the file in question will be something completely random, not open ANYWHERE on my computer and not related to any recent changes. Not only does it then fail to check it out, but it marks the file as DELETED!

Can anyone shed any light on this and perhaps offer a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem!

It was a race condition with DropBox. DropBox now supports the ability to pause syncing, so I pause DropBox, do what I need to do with Git, then resume DropBox syncing and it all goes fine.

Never even occurred to me that of course DropBox was there in the background interfering.

Comment: I take it the folder you're working in is one that DropBox watches? I use DropBox but it's not watching my working folder, yet I have the same issue

Comment: Yes all of my work is in my DropBox folder. Pausing syncing has stopped the problem 100%. If you're experiencing this problem, consider whether you have some other process that may be watching folders on your hard drive and unintentionally interfering with the write process.

Answer (score 1):

Probably not a helpful reply, but this sounds like a race condition. Try checking out the file again after the update. If that fixes it, its a bug in git or an interaction issue with the filesystem. Windows and locking files...

Comment: Yeah I noticed I could check the file out again, but oddly enough it was no longer marked as "modified" like the other surrounding files after I checked it out. The modification was only a line ending inconsistency, but I still wonder what would happen if there were real changes...